# Android draw texture extension drawing white textures

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I started writing a game for Android using OpenGL-ES and just finished the draw code which uses the glDrawTexfOES extension. When I tested it on the emulator it works fine but testing it on my Samsung Galaxy S2 it seems all the textures are drawn white.

To make sure I didn't make any mistakes I copied the source from a tutorial and ran it with the same results. The tutorial code I am using can be seen [here](http://apecoder.net/2010/11/17/using-2d-opengl-on-android-part-2/).

My textures are .PNG format and power of two and I am loading from the R.drawable folder although I have tried some other locations such as drawable-nodpi as I have seen suggested.

I have also checked the result of glGenTextures which I have read can give odd values for certain phones but seems to be giving the correct values (1,2,3..).

Does anybody know why this could be happening or suggest some other checks I can do to figure out what is going wrong?

Here is a slightly modified version of the example code I linked above to keep things simple.

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {

    gl10.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
    // Set the background colour to black ( rgba ).
    gl10.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);
    // Enable Flat Shading.
    gl10.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
    // We don't need to worry about depth testing!
    gl10.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // Set OpenGL to optimise for 2D Textures
    gl10.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    // Disable 3D specific features.
    gl10.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl10.glDisable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);

    gl10.glTexEnvx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_MODULATE);
    // Initial clear of the screen.
    gl10.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Test for draw texture

    // Test for device specific extensions
    String extensions = gl10.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS);
    boolean drawTexture = extensions.contains("draw_texture");
    Log.i("OpenGL Support - ver.:",
            gl10.glGetString(GL10.GL_VERSION) + " renderer:" +
            gl10.glGetString(GL10.GL_RENDERER) + " : " +
            (drawTexture ? "good to go!" : "forget it!!"));

    // LOAD TEXTURE

    mTextureName = new int[1];

    // Generate Texture ID
    gl10.glGenTextures(1, mTextureName, 0);
    assert gl10.glGetError() == GL10.GL_NO_ERROR;

    // Bind texture id / target (we want 2D of course)
    gl10.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,  mTextureName[0]);

     // Open and input stream and read the image
    InputStream is = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.asteroid);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Build our crop region to be the size of the bitmap (ie full image)
    mCrop = new int[4];
    mCrop[0] = 0;
    mCrop[1] = imageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    mCrop[2] = imageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    mCrop[3] = -bitmap.getHeight();


    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    assert gl10.glGetError() == GL10.GL_NO_ERROR;

    bitmap.recycle();
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int i, int i1) {

    gl10.glViewport(0, 0, i, i1);
    /*
     * Set our projection matrix. This doesn't have to be done each time we
     * draw, but usually a new projection needs to be set when the viewport
     * is resized.
     */
    float ratio = (float) i / i1;
    gl10.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl10.glLoadIdentity();
    gl10.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);
}


public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Just clear the screen and depth buffer.
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Begin drawing
    //--------------
    // These function calls can be experimented with for various effects such as transparency
    // although certain functionality maybe device specific.
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_FLAT);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl.glColor4x(0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000, 0x10000);

    // Setup correct projection matrix
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(0.0f, mWidth, 0.0f, mHeight, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // Draw all Textures
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureName[0]);
    ((GL11)gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, mCrop, 0);
    ((GL11Ext)gl).glDrawTexfOES(0, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

    // Finish drawing
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Tried glGetError on the Galaxy?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be throwing any errors, just returns 0 (GL_NO_ERROR) any place I try it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to have all the images on drawable-nodpi and nowhere else?

I don't think it may be important but try these lines just before attaching the rendering.

```
 glSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
 glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
 glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

The error can be related with transparency and PNG format.

If it doesn't work, could you please paste the code related with GLSurfaceView and the Renderer?

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried having the images only in drawable-nodpi and it yields the same results. Also added them lines and no change.

I have added code for a simple render class from the example above, the GLSurfaceView is default just with the modified renderer attached.

Comment: Code seems to be OK. Could you please tell me the 4 values of mCrop just before glTexParameteriv call?

Thanks.

Comment: Values are [0, 64, 64, -64]

Thanks for helping me so far!

Comment: I am sorry to say that it seems to be something related with Samsung Galaxy S2 and GL11 texturing funcs. Maybe you should look for an alternative (using common buffer funcs and so on). I'm sorry for that.